# How to do Two-Part Models in R

Tags: r, regression

I’m currently working with a dataset that has lots zeros in the predictor variables as well as the response variable too. The response variable is continuous and it is very skewed to the right.

I’m trying to apply a discrete-continous model where in the first level i perform a binomial logit model to model the zero o  and in the second level i perform a regression model for nonzero observations.

Stata program allows you to do this type of analysis very easily but i am using RStudio and did not find any clear packages that implement such apprach. I’d greatly appreciate it if someone can point me to which package i should be using and showing an example would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: It depends on the sort of data you have but look at the pscl and gamlss packages.

Comment: I have my dependent variable as a continuous variable with about 7k observations of zero values and the rest are positive-continuous observations. However, my independent variables also have lots of zeros as they are count data. Like the number of households, the number of family members. The number of cars etc..